# Проблема с composer-asset-plugin

Tags: yii2

Установил последней версии composer
Поставил последнюю версию composer-asset-plugin 1.2.0

Пытаюсь установить yii2 через композер
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic 
Вылетает ошибка

- yiisoft/yii2 2.0.9 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.

  - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.8 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
  - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.7 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
  - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.6 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
  - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.5 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
  - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 >=2.0.5 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9].

Погуглив, рецепта не нашел. Все равно вылетает одна и та жа ошибка. Подскажите, плиз, что делать.

Решил все снести и заново поставить композер на макбук согласно инструкции https://www.abeautifulsite.net/installing-composer-on-os-x

curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/

vim ~/.bash_profile

alias composer="php /usr/local/bin/composer.phar"

Далее через терминал поставил плагин composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0" (папки bower-asset в папке .composer не обнаружил)

Запустил через терминал в рабочей папки composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic и вылетают те же самые ошибки, что требуется requires bower-asset/jquery 2.*@stable

пробуя разные советы из форумах и на стековерфлоу так и не смог разобраться почему не ставится bower-asset/jquery через плагин fxp/composer-asset-plugin (пробовал разные версии)

в итоге поставил yii2 в ручную, но все же не дает пок, чем вызвана проблема с композером. У кого были похожие проблемы с установкой на мак плиз отпишите как их решали. Спасибо!

Comment: `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` какой командой устанавливали?

Comment: composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"

Answer (score 1):

Если вам не нужны глобальные настройки. Или вы создаёте свой шаблон приложения. У меня такие ситуации возникали (Когда используются разные версии Yii для разных сайтов) 
Можете попробовать так:

Создать минимальный файл composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "v1.1.4"
    },
    "extra": {
       "asset-installer-paths": {
         "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
       }
    }
}
```

Установить сам composer assets (Данный шаг нужно проделывать и после переноса на новый сервер. Обычно тоже помогает)

```
composer update "fxp/composer-asset-plugin"
```

Только после этого доставляем нужные пакеты

```
composer require "yiisoft/yii2":"2.0.9"
```

А дальше все остальное уже как обычно

Answer (score 1):

Мне помогло обновление касперского фри, потому что он блочил SSL2

Answer (score 0):

по этим кодам установи.

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic 2.0.9
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"
composer update yiisoft/yii2 yiisoft/yii2-composer bower-asset/jquery.inputmask
```

после заходишь в basic папку и

```
init.bat
```

//там '0'    'y'

```
yii migrate
```

если после этого не будет работать, то установи другой composer

Comment: не совсем понял, в терминале строку composer update yiisoft/yii2 yiisoft/yii2-composer bower-asset/jquery.inputmask из какой папки запускать, требует composer.json. из /user/.composer/ ?

Comment: Надо с начало в серверной папке создать папку под названием сайта, после в этой папке уже в cmd написать те команды.

Comment: скачай composer.phar и вставляй в папке с именем сайта.

Comment: что-то не выходит composer update yiisoft/yii2 yiisoft/yii2-composer bower-asset/jquery.inputmask
Package "yiisoft/yii2" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Package "yiisoft/yii2-composer" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Package "bower-asset/jquery.inputmask" listed for update is not installed. Ignoring.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update

Answer (score 0):

проблема не решена, несколько раз сносил composer и ставил все заново, потом fxp/composer-asset-plugin все равно вылетает ошибка вида yiisoft/yii2 2.0.9 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.@stable может с OS X El Capitan 10.11.3 есть какие-то особенности, еще у меня стоит MAMP 3.5

Comment: Предположу что дело в том, что когда вы ставите через global плагин, то он виден везде. Попробуйте почистить кэш `composer clear-cache`. Вы пробовали мой метод описанный выше? Также возможен конфликт из-за различий в версиях обусловленных `"minimum-stability"`

Comment: да, ваш метод пробовал (не сработал), кэш тоже пробовал чистить, удалял композер совсем и ставил заново. как решить возможную проблему конфликта версий?

Comment: И что написало за ошибку? На каком этапе?

Comment: Тоже El Capitan у меня.
http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/2016/08/19/0012/2001/813009/09/ddf7d0f369.png

Comment: и не через глобал тоже пробовал php composer.phar ...

Comment: написало ошибку   `Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 2.0.9 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.9].
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.9 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.`

Comment: composer selfupdate, тоже попробуйте. почему-то не находит у вас пакет bower, к тому же ищет в stable. Вы точно делаете всё по моей инструкции? В пустую папку, всё с начала. Потому что stable там не указан и должно тянуть dev

Comment: все сначала в новой папке где лежит файл composer.phar создаю файл    composer.json c указанным вами текстом, далее по команде `php composer.phar update "fxp/composer-asset-plugin"` получаю:
`Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing fxp/composer-asset-plugin (v1.1.4)
    Loading from cache

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files`

Comment: далее по команде `php composer.phar require "yiisoft/yii2":"2.0.9" `   получаю:  `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 2.0.9 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.9].
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.9 requires bower-asset/jquery.inputmask ~3.2.2 -> no matching package found.`

Comment: делаю `php composer.phar selfupdate` получаю
`Updating to version 1.2.0 (stable channel).
    Downloading: 100%         
Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 0aec42521b7210f66fefaf53a02ff9e4def0bdc0`

Comment: далее опять `php composer.phar require "yiisoft/yii2":"2.0.9"` и в итоге `Problem 1 - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 2.0.9 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.9]. - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.9 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.`

Comment: На днях тоже возникла такая ситуация но правда с 2.0.8.
http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/2016/08/25/0012/2001/813009/09/0b176e16fd.png
И все завелось. Поэтому крайне странно что у вас не получается

Comment: ваще без понятия, перепробовал наверно все рекомендации какие смог найти на стековерфлоу, ничего не помогло

Answer (score 0):

А версию "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:1.2.1" пробовал а то у тебя написана 1.2.0 может к yii 2.0.9 подходит только 1.2.1?

Comment: пробовал, тоже самое